# Erro ao acessar pelo localhost:8000/perfil

Tags: python, django

página perfis.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ConnectedIn</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Detalhe Perfil</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^$', 'perfis.views.index'),
    url(r'^perfis/\d+$', 'perfis.views.exibir')
    )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def exibir(request):
    return render(request, 'perfil.html')
```

Da esse erro na página

P

```
age not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/perfil
Using the URLconf defined in connectedin.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^$
The current URL, perfil, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: Também parece que você possui o *template* com o nome `perfis.html` e na *view* chamou o `perfil.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que no seu `urls.py` você está mapeando sua view pra uma URL diferente da que você está acessando. Veja:

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url(r'^$', 'perfis.views.index'),
    url(r'^perfis/\d+$', 'perfis.views.exibir')  # <- aqui
)
```

Naquela linha o Django vai estar esperando algo como `/perfis/1` ou algum outro número, e você está acessando somente com `/perfis/`. Pra que dê certo, você só precisa remover o `\d+` dessa url.